# Total order in the power set of the real line

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is it possible to define **constructively** a total order in the power set of the real line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. It is consistent with ZF that there is no linear ordering of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$.

Andres Caicedo wrote a rather detailed answer to this on [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26861/explicit-ordering-on-set-with-larger-cardinality-than-r/26893#26893).