# Total ordering on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, cardinals, order-topology

Is there a total ordering on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, the set of all subsets of $\Bbb R$, such that the set of *countable subsets* is dense in it?

(Given a total ordering $(X,>)$, a set $A\subseteq X$ is *dense* in $X$, if, for any two distinct $x,y\in X$, there is an $a\in A$ such that $x<a<y$.)

I think that I could make something work if I use the well-ordering theorem on $\Bbb R$, but I have no idea how to do it without the axiom of choice. I don't even know if *any* total ordering on $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ exists without choice.

Comment: @bof Typo, I meant $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ in both cases.

Comment: Without axiom of choice, you can not even construct a total ordering on the powerset of reals. See [the thread in Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/a/26893/48041).

Comment: Also on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223842/is-the-set-s-of-functions-s-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-from-the-rea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the continuum hypothesis is true, and let $\prec$ be a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ with order-type $\omega_1$.  Consider the induced lexicographic order on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$: that is, $A<B$ iff there is some $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\in B$, $x\not\in A$, and for all $y\prec x$, $y\in A$ iff $y\in B$.  Then the countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are dense.  Indeed, if $A<B$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is as above, let $C=B\cap \{y:y\preceq x\}$.  Then $C$ is countable and $A<C\leq B$.

More generally, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, this gives a total ordering on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ with a dense subset of size $2^{<\kappa}$ (namely, the lexicographic order and the subsets of cardinality $<\kappa$).  In particular, if $\mathfrak{c}=2^{<\mathfrak{c}}$, this gives an ordering on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ with a dense subset of size $\mathfrak{c}$, which can then be identified with the countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You don't need to assume the continuum hypothesis. You just need the fact that $|\Bbb R|$ is equal to some ordinal, and this follows from the well-ordering theorem. Right? (Or are you saying that we don't need choice as long as the continuum hypothesis is true?)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: No, you just get the subsets of size $<2^\omega$ dense in the order, as in Eric’s second paragraph.

Comment: Also, what about the finite subsets of $\Bbb R$? Are they also dense?